# Cyrillic issues with EF

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have an application, which uses EF 5 with .NET connector 6.8.3 for mysql and mysql for visual studio 1.1.3 I have a table which has collumns with collation utf8. The problem is when my entities have properties with cyrilic characters such as `пешо, пешо` when I call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` the query sent is:

```
140417 11:20:59    23 Init DB   applicantsdb
           23 Query SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
           23 Query BEGIN
           23 Query UPDATE `Applicants` SET `Note`='????, ????' WHERE `Id` = 10
           23 Query COMMIT
```

I double checked the entities, right before `SaveChanges()` there are no problems (they have their properties with cyrilic characters).

Executing the query from workbench

```
UPDATE `Applicants` SET `Note`='пешо, пешо' WHERE `Id` = 10
```

Also no problems (I can see the note with cyrilic in the database) and when I call `dbContext.Applicants.ToList()` I do get entities with cyrilic characters. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Open Entity Model Browser and find your `Note` property. It should be set as `Unicode = true`

Comment: @Andrew it is, but still this problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you work with mysql...

Just add the `Charset` configuration to your connection string:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString=".....; Charset=utf8;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-3-51/specifying-character-set/